# InlineKeyboardButton are limited in InlineKeyboardMarkup ? telegram bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I Use C# and [telegram.bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots) and want create dynamic `InlineKeyboardMarkup`

```
private static InlineKeyboardMarkup InlinePostsKeyboard;
private static List<string> PostsTitle;
...
PostsTitle = (from p in dba.BlogPosts select p.Subject).Take(4).ToList();

var inlineButtons = PostsTitle.Select(title => new[] { InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(title, title) }).ToArray();
InlinePostsKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(inlineButtons);

...
Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(Chat.Id, e.Message.Text, replyMarkup: InlinePostsKeyboard);`
```

as you see in above code bot most show 4 InlineKeyboardButton (per line) , but does not show anything !
Just enough change `....Take(4).ToList();` to 3 or less than 4 (ex : 3 , 2 or 1) and you will see that the buttons will be displayed correctly

I want to know the reason for this
Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: What the response from Telegram API says?

Comment: It seems an error occurs  : `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Bad Request: BUTTON_DATA_INVALID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a limit on number of inline keyboard rows/buttons it is definitely more than 3.

Log & check what you are sending to Telegram API. I suspect one of your blog post `p.Subject` return empty string or too long string or something that Telegram does not allow.

Also make sure the library you are using does escape values properly (*e.g. replaces special characters like `"`*)

By the way, why would you pass post subject as `callback_data`? Would not it be better to pass post ID as something like `post?id=123`?

Answer (score 2):

In one button row you can fit a maximum of 8 buttons. If you have more than 8 buttons, you have to put them into multiple rows.

I've written a (TypeScript) utility function to split the buttons array:

```
evenlySplitArray<T>(arrayToSplit: T[]): T[][] {
  if (!Array.isArray(arrayToSplit)) {
    return [[]];
  }

  const length = arrayToSplit.length;
  // Last row can contain one element more.
  const maxElementsPerRow = 5;
  const numberOfRows = Math.ceil(length / maxElementsPerRow);
  const elementsPerRow = Math.round(length / numberOfRows);

  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    // Add remainder to last row
    const end = i === numberOfRows - 1 ? length : (i + 1) * elementsPerRow;
    const split = arrayToSplit.slice(i * elementsPerRow, end);
    result.push(split);
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

The limit on the `callback_data` is 1-64 bytes, e.g. a JWT does not fit.